# Python virtual assistant does not work with Wikipedia python import

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I recently made a virtual assistant like Alexa (the wake word), it can tell me time and play videos on YouTube, but when I ask it for a specific piece of info such as " how tall is mount. Everest" I get no specific response and it just says "Repeat command again". I used the Wikipedia import to pull information off for people. How can I use this for general facts I ask? And as a side note is there any way to have it only wake up when it hears the wake word, rather than always listening? The code is posted below:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import pywhatkit
import datetime
import wikipedia

listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)


def greeting():
    engine.say("Hello I'm Alexa. How can help you?")


def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'Alexa' in command:
                command = command.replace('Alexa', '')
                print(command)
    except:
        pass
    return command


def run_Alexa():
    command = take_command()
    print(command)
    if 'play' in command:
        song = command.replace('play', '')
        talk('playing ' + song)
        pywhatkit.playonyt(song)
    elif 'time' in command:
        time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M %p')
        talk('Current time is ' + time)
    elif 'who is this' in command:
        person = command.replace('who is ', '')
        info = wikipedia.summary(person, 1)
        print(info)
        talk(info)
    else:
        talk('Please say the command again.')


while True:
    run_Alexa()
```

Comment: I believe your objective as stated in "And as a side note is there any way to have it only wake up with it hears the wake word, rather than always listening? " is not achievable, since to identify the "wake-word" it must listen continuously.  How you process input before the 'wake-word' is determined by your program.

Comment: With regard to your main issue, the code provided doesn't demonstrate how you are interfacing with the internet.  Please provide a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example")